# How to structure this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

What type of sentence should be structured to say that:

*Use this word and make it has a positive meaning?*

> **a) Use this word in a way that it has a positive meaning.**
>
> **b) Use this word in a way that it's having a positive meaning.**
>
> **c) Use this word in a way that it means something positive.**

1) Do these sentences are grammatically correct and suitable to tell the situation?

2) If these sentences are grammatically incorrect or don't give the overall gist clearly, then what type of sentence should be structured?

Comment: I would use the **future tense** in the second part of the sentence like this: `Use this word in a way that it would have a positive meaning` OR `Use this word in a way that it would mean something positive`.

Answer (score 1):

They may be grammatically correct as they stand, but my ear prefers the addition of "such" in a or c:

> Use this word in such a way that it has a positive meaning.
>
> Use this word in such a way that it means something positive.

Another possibility is to use "so that":

> Use the word so that it has a positive meaning.
>
> Use the word so that it means something positive.

Sentence b does not sound right to me, with or without the use of "such" or "so".

See also: 
[Discerning between in a way that, in such a way that, and in doing so?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34009/discerning-between-in-a-way-that-in-such-a-way-that-and-in-doing-so)

Comment: "so" is the right conjunction here.